# Installing icuin in gcc

Tags: gcc, unicode, icu

I am trying to install a unicode library named `icuin`. It is related to `icuuc`, but I haven't been able to find how to download it for a project. Even Google searches haven't turned out much.

I have downloaded compiled libs and dlls for windows and added `icuin` and `icuuc` to the list of libs. In GCC I believe it would be `-licuuc -licuin`, but haven't been successful installing that codebase (to either run separately or in Docker).

Has anyone been successful in installing `icuin` on a Linux platform? If so, how would that be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [How To Package ICU](https://raw.githack.com/unicode-org/icu/master/icu4c/readme.html#HowToPackage), `icuin` is the Windows name. The corresponding Linux name is `libicui18n`.

Like many other C libraries, this is bundled into one package. Installing the development package is sufficient to make it available to compilers.

On my system:

```
› rpm -q --whatprovides 'pkgconfig(icu-i18n)'
libicu-devel-64.2-3.3.x86_64
```

The Debian equivalent is [`libicu-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/libicu-dev).